# Facebook omniauth rails NoAuthorizationCodeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

Hello guys I am trying to integrate facebook login in my rails application 
I included gems in my gem file

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 1.4.1'
```

and in my omniauth file

an in my routes.rb file

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'users#screate',:as => :callback
```

i have added in my omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '632837163475474', 'b1db948ee52851623397e66b293ff45a',{provider_ignores_state: true}
end
```

but when I try to login I get the following error

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError
must pass either a `code` parameter or a signed request (via `signed_request` parameter or a `fbsr_XXX` cookie)
```

if I remove 
{provider_ignores_state: true}
I get following error

```
csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

Comment: You shouldn't share you Facebook App ID and Secret. I suggest you regenerate those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to login, are you linking to "/auth/facebook"?  This URL sets up the signed request that your error is suggesting you don't have...